# Is is possible to get notifications when user submits data in ShinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rstudio-server, shiny-reactivity

Pretty self-explanatory, I am hoping to expand my app to push notifications when users upload new data.

Currently, the data is pushed to the server once user clicks a ‘submit’ btn. However, I have to go in the corresponding file to see if new uploads have been made.

I am thinking that I can add another observer (observeEvent) to the actionButton (submit) but the closest I can get is combining html to ‘sendmail’ to the admin account. This is obviously not automated and is little better than the user emailing admin themselves.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I would send from an email created especially to contact your admin account, this way you can choose exactly what information you need